# Can I force lein to ignore dependencies from any code external to current Clojure project?

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I'm calling some Clojure (1.8) code in a larger Java project that I don't entirely have control over. Recently some code has been added to the parent that's causing conflicts with the HTTP client `clj-http`.

From my Clojure project, here's the output of `lein deps :tree|grep http`:

```
[clj-http "3.7.0"]    
  [org.apache.httpcomponents/httpasyncclient "4.1.3" :exclusions [[org.clojure/clojure]]] 
    [org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore-nio "4.4.6"]    
  [org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient "4.5.3" :exclusions [[org.clojure/clojure]]]    
  [org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore "4.4.6" :exclusions [[org.clojure/clojure]]]    
  [org.apache.httpcomponents/httpmime "4.5.3" :exclusions [[org.clojure/clojure]]]
```

Running `mvn dependency:tree|grep http` for the other project returns the following (note that this project is also a child of the parent):

```
[INFO] +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.1:compile
```

Is there a way I can ignore conflicts originating outside of my Clojure code, in lein (or otherwise)?

Comment: What is going wrong?  What is the error message?

Comment: java.lang.Exception: The application script threw an exception: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE BSF info: Get dimension data at line: 0 column: columnNo

Answer (score 4):

it's necessary to slog through the conflicts and fix them. There are two approaches:

- Exclusions: 
  Exclude each dependency that is reported in `lein deps tree` from each of the upstream dependencies where it's provided. This gives you complete control when you need to make sure a transitive dependency is not included. It can though ... "be a bit of a bother" ;-)
- Managed Dependencies: 
  You can also add a `managed-dependencies` section to your project.clj where you specify the exact version of libraries that will be used, regardless of the resolution of other transitive dependencies. This is a somewhat more blunt instrurment, and one i tend to turn to.

A random example from a project:

```
  :managed-dependencies [[http-kit "2.3.0"]
                         [org.clojure/clojure "1.9.0"]
                         [ring/ring-core "1.6.0"]
                         [ring/ring-jetty-adapter "1.6.0"]
                         ... lots more ...]
```

Comment: Thanks Arthur - I found a hacky workaround, which is too specific to be worth sharing, so won't have chance to investigate this at mo. Will :managed-dependencies prevent conflicts from other versions of the same dependency that happen to be prior in the class path to the ones being introduced by lein?

Comment: yes, managed dependencies is applied last, as lein is building the classpath. As I understand it it gets the final say, unless you are passing JVM options that manually mangle the classpath